# SQL how to handle the empty table with 0 value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sqlite

Hi guys I'm trying this problem with a Table called nobel have (yr,subject) column

The answer provided for this question is below
Pick the code that shows the amount of years where no Medicine awards were given

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT yr) FROM nobel
   WHERE yr NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Medicine')
```

However, my question is, if the Medicine is given every year , which mean our query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT yr) FROM nobel WHERE yr NOT IN(....)
```

will select from an empty table, then instead of return 0, it will be error, then how to deal with this case?

Thanks so much !

Comment: Please tag the correct database. Is it mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: I don't see any error here. Could you show error messages you get? I think it would return 0 normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL()` of mysql.

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT yr), 0) FROM nobel WHERE yr NOT IN(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

If subject column is used in the filter condition then the count column can be taken as below.

SELECT count(yr) FROM nobel WHERE subject <> 'Medicine'.

You can just run the above query to get the year count.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every year at least one award is given (i.e. there's a record for every year):

```
select distinct n.yr, (select count(*) from nobel n1 where n1.subject = 'Medicine' and n1.yr = n.yr) cnt
  from nobel n
```